# Embed XPS in HTML

Tags: html, xps

how can an XPS document be embedded into HTML?

The solution has to work in Internet Explorer 8, only. I know that IE can display XPS directly, but I need more control of the way the pages are displayed. Probably this can be solved with an object tag, but I couldn't find any resources.

Edit:
I need to control the zoom factor and scrollbars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an iframe to your page and set the source to point to the xps document.

Comment: Ok, this works. Is there a way to influence how the page is displayed (zoom, scrollbars, etc)

Comment: @michael not much.  The way XPS docs are displayed in the browser leaves much to be desired.